# Infinite Redirects Taking Place after deleting .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently migrated a wordpress site to a digital ocean droplet. I switched the DNS from namecheap to digital ocean and put the old wordpress site in a directory called /old/.

I then created an .htaccess file and tried to redirect my the root directory to /old using this:

`Redirect 301 / /old`

Nothing happened. I followed a couple guides and went into my apache2.conf file and changed the `<Directory /var/www/>` entry to `AllowOverride All`. I then ran `sudo a2enmod Rewrite`.

The first then that happened was that visiting my root directory redirected to /oldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldoldold/. I removed the .htaccess files and restarted Apache. Nothing changed.

I then went back into apache2.conf and changed `AllowOverride All` back to `AllowOverride None`. I then ran `sudo a2dismod Rewrite.`

I'm still getting the infinite redirects. Both `/` and `/old` redirect to /oldoldoldoldoldoldoldold...

I've restarted apache a bunch using `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. Nothing has helped; I'm still getting the redirects.

Sub directories, such as /old/wp-admin, work fine.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 301 code means the redirect is intended to be permanent, as opposed to 302 which is temporary. Your browser cached them the first time you tried them, so any future changes you made to the Web server didn't actually matter, since your browser assumed the "permanent" redirect was still there instead of even hitting the server again. You need to clear your browser's cache to fix it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Site didn't redirect on my phone. Any idea why I got the loop in the first place?